# RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper swipe undo

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, swipe, swipelayout

Делаю свайп с удалением для RecyclerView 
ItemTouchHelper

есть FrameLayout с двумя лайоутами верхний front свайпится в бок.
а под ним второй layout_back с кнопками "Скрыть" и "Отмена".

После свайпа, под ним появляется второй слой с кнопками, но почему то клики на них срабатывают не с первого раза.

```
public class MyItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public MyItemTouchHelper(RecyclerView mRecyclerView, ItemAdapter itemAdapter) {
        super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
        this.itemAdapter = itemAdapter;
        this.recyclerView = mRecyclerView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_IDLE, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) | makeFlag(ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeDirs(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemCancel.setEnabled(true);
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemDelete.setEnabled(true);
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContainer.bringToFront();
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContainer.invalidate();
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "DELETE " + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                itemAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

            }
        });
        ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "CANCEL " + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContainer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
                ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemCancel.setEnabled(false);
                ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemDelete.setEnabled(false);
                ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContext.bringToFront();
                ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).itemContext.invalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        if (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() == -1) {
            return;
        }
        if (actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE) {
            if (dX > 0 || dX < 0) {
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).getSwipableView(), dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
        View foreground = ((ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder) viewHolder).getSwipableView();
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foreground);
    }
}
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/contprice"
    layout="@layout/quest_price"
    style="@style/wrap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

<LinearLayout
    style="@style/wrap.linear"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/contprice"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_weight="0.4">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/quest_title"
        android:text="Рассказать друзьям"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details"
        style="@style/quest_detail"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_back**:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    android:textColor="#0eb0a0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Отмена"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:textColor="#e6007e"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Скрыть"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

пытаюсь вынести **layout_back** на передний план 
`bringToFront()` и перерисовываю `invalidate()`, но все равно не помогает, срабатывают клики на кнопках раз на 5.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Проблему решили? Тоже стало актаульно...

Comment: @dramf пока еще нет

Comment: решил проблему слоев

Comment: поделитесь решением?мне уже не актуально, но интересно )

Comment: @dfarm  
при onSwiped перерисовываю холдер со вторым слоем

Comment: @Trunksssj очень интересно, можете показать как вы это сделали?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko
в методе 

    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        itemAdapter.redrawViewHolder(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

в адаптере

 public void redrawViewHolder(int position) {
        
            notifyItemChanged(position);
    
    }

Answer (score 1):

Два дня просидев с аналогичной проблемой, решил использовать AndroidSwipeLayout: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout
собрал за час.

Comment: да, я видел эту либу

Comment: я ничего лучшего не нашел...

Comment: при onSwiped перерисовываю холдер со вторым слоем